# Disable a single link with rewrite_hash_links in silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

I have a link in my page.ss that needs rewrite_hash_links set to false.

```
<a href="#menu" class="menu-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></a>
```

I've found the documentation but have no idea how to apply it to just the one link. https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/templates/how_tos/disable_anchor_links/

Answer (score 0):

So, do you want the `#menu` link to go to `<root of site>/#menu`?
This is what simply disabling the rewrite would do, assuming you still include the `base` tag in your source.

In any case the rewrite_hash_links functionality **only applies** to unqualified hash links.  In other words if you put an absolute URL in the link, it shouldn't be rewritten.

**Example**

```
<a href="{$BaseURL}#menu">...</a>
```

or:

```
<a href="{$AbsoluteLink}#menu">...</a>
```